# Selecting next SELECT in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

## jQuery

```
$("select[id^='_taskAssignedTo_']").each(function(id) {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
        $(this).next().find("select[id^='_taskStatus_']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

## HTML

```
<td>
    <select id="_taskAssignedTo_1"> <!-- options --> </select>
<td>
<td>
    <select id="_taskStatus_1"> <!-- options --> </select>
<td>
```

I am looping through and finding the first `select` because it has the value I need to search for and I want to enable the `select` next to it called, `_taskStatus_1`. There are many, so it is important I use the "start with" syntax.

The code above does not work. I am not sure if I need to use `next`, `find`, something else, or a combination?

Comment: it is better to provide jsfiddle link or something like that

Comment: @Neo the problem is perfectly clear in the provided code.

Comment: Ideally, when you want to add a CSS hook to more than one element, use a class instead of an id. If you then want to also assign unique identifiers to elements with that class use data-id or #prefix-{someid}, as required.

Comment: @JasonP yes it is but it makes "testing of code" easier

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but why can't you just use: `$(#_taskStatus_1)`?

Comment: the number at the end is dynamically generated.  this is just one example above.

Comment: Yes, but let's say your number is stored in the variable `i`. Why can't you do: `$('#_taskStatus_' + i);`. That is *much* faster than all this back and forth DOM walking.

Comment: @KickingLettuce Could you please show us the code where you are generating the number? I strongly suspect there is a much easier (and more efficient) way to do this than you have currently settled on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
$(this).closest("td").next("td").find("select[id^='_taskStatus_']");
```

You have to first travel back to your `td` (closest) - then to the next `td` (next) - then `find` the element you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(this).parent().next().find("select[id^='_taskStatus_']").prop("disabled", false);
```